# Drawing on a canvas element dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am trying to learn some new things and thought I experiment with canvas a bit.
I got a canvas element that loads an image that i want to draw over once i click an anchor.

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:" id="testClick">Click Me</a>
<canvas id="test" width=400 height=400></canvas>
```

Javascript

```
var c = document.getElementById("test");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);  
};
img.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/400/400/abstract';

$("#test").on('click', function() {
    var c2 = document.getElementById('test').getContext('2d');
  c2.fillStyle = '#76ff03';
  c2.beginPath();
  c2.lineTo(100, 50);
  c2.lineTo(50, 100);
  c2.lineTo(0, 90);
  c2.closePath();
  c2.fill();
});
```

All its meant to do is draw a red triangle on top the image that is loaded previously by the canvas.
Unfortunately i don't get anywhere with this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This works for me, [jsBin](https://jsbin.com/cibokaliwo/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: @fordcars the link doesn't work mate.

Comment: Poo, try this: https://jsfiddle.net/pmd5xt7y/

Comment: Yea that worked, pretty much looks like my code now. Found error was with jquery for some reason. Changed the version and boom worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you are using the "$" function, which you are probably expecting from JQuery, but you are not including the JQuery script on your file.

> `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>`

Apart from that, your code seems to work properly.

By the way, the triangle you're drawing is actually green. If you want it to be red you could set

> c2.fillStyle = '#ff0000';

Comment: Yea I copied the code that I modifed later gence green :). Yes i have jquery already running. I changed the jquery version and it works now (to a degree), but now I got another problem where the image is stretched inside the canvas rather than resizing it. Still investigating